# android crash /system/lib/libhwui.so

Tags: android, crash

there is a crash i have got sometimes , it seems a jni crash , but my application have not any jni code .  it's is a graphic application , and will load some pictures .

could anyone told me how to find the problem . what's the libhwui.so .

```
 I/DEBUG   (  141): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000000e8
I/DEBUG   (  141):  r0 ffffffff  r1 000000e8  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  r4 ffffffff  r5 000000e8  r6 018fea18  r7 018fe9c8
I/DEBUG   (  141):  r8 40baa190  r9 018fea40  10 0000001c  fp 0000001c
I/DEBUG   (  141):  ip 40bab590  sp be818c98  lr 4005510c  pc 4005510c  cpsr 68000010
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d0  4300000043000000  d1  44d0000043000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d2  41d0000000000040  d3  4000000000000002
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d4  4000000040200000  d5  4000000000000002
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d6  4000000040000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d8  43e6000040000000  d9  403c800000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d10 403c800000000000  d11 4038000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d12 447a000042363498  d13 3f6ed2573c23d700
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d14 3f4959923ed2d2d3  d15 00000000c1600000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d16 c000000000000000  d17 c000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d18 4000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 8000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d22 c000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 3fca515880000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 3fca515880000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  141):  scr 68000013
I/DEBUG   (  141): 
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #00  pc 0000510c  /system/lib/libcutils.so (android_atomic_add)
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #01  pc 0000ae3e  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #02  pc 0000ae4e  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #03  pc 000162f2  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #04  pc 000163a6  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #05  pc 000226a0  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android10VectorImpl5_growEjj)
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #06  pc 000226d2  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android10VectorImpl8insertAtEPKvjj)
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #07  pc 0002280e  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android16SortedVectorImpl3addEPKv)
I/DEBUG   (  141):          #08  pc 00016874  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141): 
I/DEBUG   (  141): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  141): 400550ec e1853f92 e3530000 1afffffa e8bd8070  .?....S.....p...
I/DEBUG   (  141): 400550fc e92d4070 e1a04000 e1a05001 ebffffd1  p@-..@...P......
I/DEBUG   (  141): 4005510c e1950f9f e0802004 e1853f92 e3530000  ..... ...?....S.
I/DEBUG   (  141): 4005511c 1afffffa e8bd8070 e1a01000 e3e00000  ....p...........
I/DEBUG   (  141): 4005512c eafffff2 e1a01000 e3a00001 eaffffef  ................
I/DEBUG   (  141): 
I/DEBUG   (  141): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c58  01887204  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c5c  be818db8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c60  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c64  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c68  00000368  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c6c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c70  00000310  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c78  014d84e0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c7c  0000001c  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c80  00000310  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c84  0000001c  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c88  00001906  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c8c  400cee59  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c90  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c94  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  141): #00 be818c98  000000e8  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818c9c  0000004d  
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818ca0  018fea18  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818ca4  40b92e41  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (  141): #01 be818ca8  01856aa8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  141):     be818cac  40b92e53  /system/lib/libhwui.so
```

i have see a crash agin

```
I/DEBUG   (10037): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (10037):  r0 deadbaad  r1 00000001  r2 40000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  r4 00000000  r5 00000027  r6 400f34c8  r7 401025d8
I/DEBUG   (10037):  r8 0146dc68  r9 40102598  10 5bdf7b8c  fp 5bdf7c24
I/DEBUG   (10037):  ip ffffffff  sp 5bdf79e8  lr 400d45c9  pc 400d0958  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d0  72656c69706d6f43  d1  726f7470008ed744
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d2  617369646f6e5f57  d3  6f6c6f685f656c50
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d4  9933333399333333  d5  9933333399333333
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d6  00d2aff099333333  d7  000000434e5f30de
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d16 0000000700000001  d17 40c4400000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d18 4146605000000000  d19 bfb1be5a93a83e1d
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d20 3f1155e54e7e8408  d21 bebbbc6c1a570a20
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 3fede16b9c24a98f
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d24 3e66376972bea4d0  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (10037):  scr 80000012
I/DEBUG   (10037): 
D/ti_hwc  (  142): [handle_uevents] :: Uevent : change@/devices/platform/omap/omap_i2c.1/i2c-1/1-0049/twl6030_bci/power_supply/battery
D/PowerManagerService(  292): mPowerState = SCREEN_BRIGHT_BIT SCREEN_ON_BIT 
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #00  pc 00017958  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #01  pc 000137e2  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #02  pc 00015b20  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree)
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #03  pc 00016198  /system/lib/libc.so (free)
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #04  pc 000009bc  /system/lib/libstdc++.so (_ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t)
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #05  pc 00016afe  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #06  pc 00016b10  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #07  pc 0001640a  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #08  pc 00016bc4  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #09  pc 0000d752  /system/lib/libhwui.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #10  pc 0000d8e0  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer11DisplayListD1Ev)
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #11  pc 0005e896  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #12  pc 0001edb0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
I/DEBUG   (10037):          #13  pc 000590f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
I/DEBUG   (10037): 
I/DEBUG   (10037): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d0938 4623b15c 2c006824 e026d1fb b12368db  \.#F$h.,..&..h#.
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d0948 21014a17 6011447a 48124798 24002527  .J.!zD.`.G.H'%.$
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d0958 f7f47005 2106eeb4 ef50f7f5 460aa901  .p.....!..P....F
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d0968 f04f2006 94015380 94029303 eb0cf7f5  . O..S..........
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d0978 4622a905 f7f52002 f7f4eb16 2106eea0  .."F. .........!
I/DEBUG   (10037): 
I/DEBUG   (10037): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d45a8 41f0e92d 46804c0c 447c2600 68a56824  -..A.L.F.&|D$h.h
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d45b8 e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628  gh.....0.+..(F.G
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d45c8 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f4 d1ee2c00  .CT5...7..$h.,..
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d45d8 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00028f96 41f0e92d  0F..........-..A
I/DEBUG   (10037): 400d45e8 fb01b086 9004f602 461f4815 4615460c  .........H.F.F.F
I/DEBUG   (10037): 
I/DEBUG   (10037): memory map around addr deadbaad:
I/DEBUG   (10037): be7f9000-be81a000 [stack]
I/DEBUG   (10037): (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (10037): ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
I/DEBUG   (10037): 
I/DEBUG   (10037): stack:
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79a8  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79ac  5bdf79e8  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79b0  400fd840  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79b4  0000000c  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79b8  400fd7d4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79bc  401028c8  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79c0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79c4  400d45c9  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79c8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79cc  5bdf79fc  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79d0  400f34c8  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79d4  401025d8  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79d8  0146dc68  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79dc  400d3735  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79e0  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79e4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10037): #00 5bdf79e8  5bdf79e4  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79ec  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79f0  400f34ac  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79f4  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79f8  5bdf7a14  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf79fc  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a00  5bdf7a14  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a04  5bdf7a14  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a08  400f6a64  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a0c  400cc7e7  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037): #01 5bdf7a10  5bdf7ae8  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a14  20404040  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a18  524f4241  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a1c  474e4954  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a20  4e49203a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a24  494c4156  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a28  45482044  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a2c  41205041  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a30  45524444  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a34  49205353  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a38  6c64204e  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a3c  65657266  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a40  01417700  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a44  4034d558  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a48  013648c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a4c  401025c0  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a50  00000068  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a54  40102588  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a58  014186c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a5c  40102588  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a60  40354c80  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a64  400ceb39  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a68  409054aa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a6c  4034d558  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a70  5bdf7b20  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a78  5bdf7b28  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a7c  40354c80  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a80  40354c80  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a84  400cf19b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a88  409054aa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a8c  402c79df  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a90  5bdf7b40  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a94  402cacf7  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a98  01364880  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7a9c  40102608  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7aa0  013b5e00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7aa4  401025c0  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7aa8  00000068  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7aac  401025a0  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ab0  409054aa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ab4  401025a8  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ab8  5bdf7b68  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7abc  0145c410  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ac0  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ac4  40102558  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ac8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7acc  400cdcd5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ad0  013c2758  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ad4  40102590  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ad8  00000038  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7adc  40102534  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ae0  0145f8d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ae4  40102580  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7ae8  0146c5d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7aec  0146c5f0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7af0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7af4  40102558  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7af8  5bdf7b8c  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7afc  400cdcd5  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b00  012fb8d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b04  012fb928  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b08  01479db0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b0c  00000035  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b10  011a31e4  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b14  1c5bddbe  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b18  01479d68  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b1c  01479de8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b20  00000080  
I/DEBUG   (10037):     5bdf7b24  400ceb25  /system/lib/libc.so
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a hardware layer. Are you using `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` in an AnimationListener?

Comment: i have use PullToRefreshListView , i found this in it's code `ViewCompat.setLayerType(mRefreshableViewWrapper, value != 0 ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE
     : View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE);`

Comment: What OS is this happening on? Is it a 4.0.x device?

Comment: yes , it's android 4.0.4 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I remember seeing a crash like this and reading about a bug with 4.0.x in particular where removing a hardware layer in an AnimationListener (onAnimationEnd()) would cause this sort of crash. The solution was to post the layer transition as a Runnable. For example:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {
    //This will cause a crash
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {
    //This will work successfully
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , if this crash is caused by setLayerType , i think that is a [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) bugs , but i have no time to fix it .

Comment: Probably is. No time to fix it? It's open source; should be trivial to just change the ViewCompat.setLayerType() method to post as a runnable if layerType == LAYER_TYPE_NONE (or you could just do it for all layer types)

Comment: yes , i have not read the code carefully , i don't know it will cause some other bugs . you mean if i change `ViewCompat.setLayerType(mRefreshableViewWrapper, value != 0 ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE : View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE);` to `ViewCompat.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE);` will fix this problem ?

Comment: No, not exactly. You're probably right that you shouldn't mess with it if you're not sure what's going on, but essentially the call to setLayerType from hardware layer to no layer should be posted as a runnable, not directly in onAnimationEnd().

Comment: i have a crash again , but the stack have some different with the previous one , is it the same problem ? i have put the crash in question .

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old post but I've been struggling with a similar crash for a long time and just recently found root cause.  Here are a few more tidbits on my crash:

- crash can be in libhwui.so, libskia.so, libutils.so, or libc.so
- app is not using NDK
- strong correlation to devices.  Samsung S6/S7 and Nexus 5 had a lot of instances.  Never saw the crash on an old Kyocera

Since my app also does not have native code the stack dump/tombstone file didn't reference any of my code.  Through adhoc testing, I narrowed the source of the problem to a custom ProgressBar in the app.

The ProgressBar leveraged a TimerTask under the hood!  Thankfully I had recently bumped into [this post](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/) while researching something else.

Changed the code to a handler and haven't seen the crash since!  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Could whomever down-voted give an explanation? Developers often inherit code from others as I have so I feel this is a valid contribution to the world

Comment: Link is not working can you tell what handling you have done

Comment: Sorry the link is dead now.  Basically you instantiate Handler and Runnable objects.  Do your task in the Runnables run command, then postDelayed(this) to a UX object.  Here is another example.  https://medium.com/@dnkilic/very-simple-comparison-between-java-util-timer-and-android-os-handler-ea6749038b12

Comment: Here's a [working link](http://web.archive.org/web/20200131001301/http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/).