# Android Service not stopping self

Tags: android, service, android-windowmanager

Here's my code:

```
               @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // Get current time in nano seconds.
                long pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


                // If double click...
                if (pressTime - lastPressTime <= 300) {
                    createNotification();
                    ServiceFloating.this.stopSelf();
                    mHasDoubleClicked = true;
                }
                else {     // If not double click....
                    mHasDoubleClicked = false;
                }
                lastPressTime = pressTime; 
                initialX = paramsF.x;
                initialY = paramsF.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(event.getRawX() - initialTouchX >40)
                {
                    paramsF.x = (int)dispwidth;
                    paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout, "translationX", 100f, 0f);
                    animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
                    animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                    animY.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animY.start();
                }
                else if(initialTouchX-event.getRawX()>40){
                    paramsF.x = 0;
                    paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout, "translationX", -100f, 0f);
                    animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
                    animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                    animY.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animY.start();
                }
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(layout, paramsF);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(layout, paramsF);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

And here's my `onDestroy()`

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (safe != null) windowManager.removeView(safe);
}
```

Where `safe` is a `LinearLayout` the I attach with windowmanager object in my oncreate
The service starts and runs fine. When I call `stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceFloating.class));` on a button's on click from my main activity I can stop the service but when I try to stop the service from it's own view the app crashes and restarts with [Fatal signal 11 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651169/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-fault-addr-renderthread)

How can I stop the service from it's own view?

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the service from inside the service, sending a message from the activity to the service when you push a button for example. You need to bind the activity to the service in order to be able to send and receive messages.

I use this methods when the service receives a stop message from an activity:

```
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be stopped from the activity.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by stop the service from it's own view. A service do not have any layout. From where do you want to stop it?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatmob.floating.touch&hl=en this kind of thing is being done by services with views added to the windowmanager